# Vertically center text inside position: fixed

Tags: html, vertical-alignment

My html:

```
<body>
    <div id="click-here">
        <a href="...">
            <span>Click here</span>
        </a>
    </div>
    ...
</body>
```

My css:

```
html { 
    margin-top: 100px !important; 
}

#click-here { 
    height: 100px; 
    position: fixed; 
    top: 0;
    width: 100%; 
    z-index: 100000; 
}

#click-here a {
    background-image: url('...');
    display: block; 
    height: 60px; 
    width: 200px; 
    margin: 0 auto; 
    margin-top: 20px; 
    text-align: center; 
}
```

I want Click here to be centered inside the a element, which serves as a button. However, it is only horizontally centered. I tried vertical-align: middle on anchor, but it didn't work. I also tried setting margin-top and padding-top for span, but this is completely ignored.

Any idea what else I could try?

Comment: #click-here a { line-height: 100px; }

Comment: Hm, 100px is not a good value, but a smaller value does the job. Thanks!

Comment: Further reading: Smashing Magazine published an great and in-depth article on different CSS centering techniques a few days ago: http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2013/08/09/absolute-horizontal-vertical-centering-css/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the line-height of the anchor tag.

```
#click-hear a{
    background-image: url('...');
    display: block;
    ****line-height:50px; 
    height: 60px; 
    width: 200px; 
    margin: 0 auto; 
    margin-top: 20px; 
    text-align: center; 
}
```

Just play with the line height until it's centered. It should give you the desired result.

You could also add padding, but that would mess up the background image.

Answer (score 0):

[This example](http://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/center#vertical) from w3.org suggests using `display:table-cell` in addition with `vertical-align:middle` for this.

I have been using this solution quite often, it has always worked fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

See this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/PeSFh/ using `display: table`, `display: table-cell` and `vertical-align: middle`.